# responsive size of a d3 js chart not decreasing accordingly

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to make a buble chart reactive using d3 js. I've used a custom hook to react to the web brower's changes in sizes, but i have encountered a problem so far: when the size of the window decreases to a specified point, the limit of my chart, in the far right side won't render. To explain the problem further more, i'm displaying my data on a linear scale starting from 0, and ending at 100 in the x axis. however the bubles with the x coordinates close to 100 won't show on small devices but will show on desktop screens.
Here is an online example of my chart:codesandbox.io/s/exciting-lederberg-gj985f .
Here is a piece of the code i'm working with:
my custom react hook:

```
const useResizeObserver = (ref) => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const observeTarget = ref.current;
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        setDimensions(entry.contentRect);
      });
    });
    resizeObserver.observe(observeTarget);
    return () => {
      resizeObserver.unobserve(observeTarget);
    };
  }, [ref]);
  return dimensions;
};
```

my svg creation:

```
const BubleChart = ({ data }) => {
  const mySVGRef = useRef(null);
  const wrapperRef = useRef();
  const dimensions = useResizeObserver(wrapperRef);

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  useEffect(() => {
    var svg = d3.select(mySVGRef.current);
    console.log(dimensions);

    if (!dimensions) return;
    //so that we dont have duplication
    svg.html(null);
    svg
      // .append("svg")
      .attr("width", dimensions.width)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr("transform", `translate(${0},${margin.top * 3})`);
  
    //x axis definition
    const xscale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([0, dimensions.width * 0.85]);

    const x_axis = d3
      .axisBottom() //axis bottom positions the numbers of the axis below the axis, so we need a y translation so that the axis are really in the botom
      .scale(xscale)
      .tickValues(d3.range(0, xscale.domain()[1] + 1, 25));
    const x_tickValues = x_axis.tickValues();

    

    svg
      .append("g") // add a group element that will contain our axis The <g> element is a container that groups multiple SVG elements together
      .call(x_axis)
      .attr(
        "transform",
        `translate(${margin.left * 2},${height - margin.bottom})`
      )
      .style("stroke-width", 0.3)
      //   //remove the x axis
      .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove());
    // ticks vlaues' text
    svg.selectAll(".tick text").attr("fill", "#777");

   
  }, [data, dimensions]);



return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-lg-1"></div>
      <div className="col-lg-10 chart-div" ref={wrapperRef}>
        <svg ref={mySVGRef}></svg>
        <div ref={myTooltipRef}></div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-lg-1"></div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Comment: here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-lederberg-gj985f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with d3, so I don't know if there is a really responsive way of doing this, BUT this way works... I added a function to calculate some of the numbers based on the window size:

https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-cloud-mj2vmw

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

const useResizeObserver = (ref) => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const observeTarget = ref.current;
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        setDimensions(entry.contentRect);
      });
    });
    resizeObserver.observe(observeTarget);
    return () => {
      resizeObserver.unobserve(observeTarget);
    };
  }, [ref]);
  return dimensions;
};

const calculateEndRange = (width) => {
  if (window.innerWidth < 200) {
    return width * 0.70;
  }

  if (window.innerWidth < 300) {
    return width * 0.75;
  }

  if (window.innerWidth < 400) {
    return width * 0.8;
  }

  if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
    return width * 0.82;
  }

  if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
    return width * 0.8;
  }

  return width * 0.85;
}

const calculateMarginLeft = (marginLeft) => {

  if (window.innerWidth < 300) {
    return marginLeft * 1;
  }

  if (window.innerWidth < 400) {
    return marginLeft * 1.2;
  }

  if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
    return marginLeft * 1.5;
  }

  if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
    return marginLeft * 1.7;
  }

  if (window.innerWidth < 700) {
    return marginLeft * 1.7;
  }

  if (window.innerWidth < 800) {
    return marginLeft * 2;
  }

  if (window.innerWidth < 1000) {
    return marginLeft * 2.2;
  }

  return marginLeft * 2.7;
}

const BubleChart = ({ data }) => {
  const mySVGRef = useRef(null);
  const wrapperRef = useRef();
  const dimensions = useResizeObserver(wrapperRef);
  const myTooltipRef = useRef(null);

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  useEffect(() => {
    var svg = d3.select(mySVGRef.current);
    console.log(dimensions);

    if (!dimensions) return;
    //so that we dont have duplication
    svg.html(null);
    svg
      // .append("svg")
      .attr("width", dimensions.width)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr("transform", `translate(${0},${margin.top * 3})`);

    //x axis definition
    const xscale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([0, calculateEndRange(dimensions.width)]);

    const x_axis = d3
      .axisBottom() //axis bottom positions the numbers of the axis below the axis, so we need a y translation so that the axis are really in the botom
      .scale(xscale)
      .tickValues(d3.range(0, xscale.domain()[1] + 1, 25));
    const x_tickValues = x_axis.tickValues();

    //  y axis definition
    const yscale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

    var y_axis = d3
      .axisLeft() //axis bottom positions the numbers of the axis below the axis, so we need a y translation so that the axis are really in the botom
      .scale(yscale)
      .tickValues(d3.range(0, yscale.domain()[1] + 1, 25));
    const y_tickValues = y_axis.tickValues();
    //   .ticks((d3.max(data, (d) => d.population) - 65000) / 5000)
    // y axis implementation
    svg
      .append("g") // add a group element that will contain our axis The <g> element is a container that groups multiple SVG elements together
      .call(y_axis)
      .attr("transform", `translate(${calculateMarginLeft(margin.left)},${0})`)
      .style("stroke-width", 0.3)
      //   //remove the y axis
      .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove());
    // ticks vlaues' text
    svg.selectAll(".tick text").attr("fill", "#777");

    svg
      .append("g") // add a group element that will contain our axis The <g> element is a container that groups multiple SVG elements together
      .call(x_axis)
      .attr(
        "transform",
        `translate(${calculateMarginLeft(margin.left)},${height - margin.bottom})`
      )
      .style("stroke-width", 0.3)
      //   //remove the x axis
      .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove());
    // ticks vlaues' text
    svg.selectAll(".tick text").attr("fill", "#777");

    //adding vertical grids
    svg
      .selectAll("xGrid")
      .data(x_tickValues)
      .join("line")
      .attr("x1", (d) => xscale(d))
      .attr("x2", (d) => xscale(d))
      .attr("y1", margin.top)
      .attr("y2", height - 30)
      .attr("transform", `translate(${calculateMarginLeft(margin.left)},${0})`)
      .attr("stroke", "#e0e0e0")
      .attr("stroke-width", 0.5);

    //adding horizontal grids
    svg
      .selectAll("yGrid")
      .data(y_tickValues)
      .join("line")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("x2", calculateEndRange(dimensions.width))
      .attr("y1", (d) => yscale(d))
      .attr("y2", (d) => yscale(d))
      .attr("transform", `translate(${calculateMarginLeft(margin.left)},${0})`)
      .attr("stroke", "#e0e0e0")
      .attr("stroke-width", 0.5);

    //create the tooltip

    const tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip");

    //adding the circles
    svg
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .on("mouseenter", (event, d) => {
        tooltip
          .style("display", "block")
          .style("left", `${xscale(d["x"]) + margin.left * 4}px`) //the aditions are caused by the translations of my graph
          .style("top", `${yscale(d["y"]) + height - margin.bottom}px`)
          .html(
            `<strong>x coordinate:</strong> ${d["x"]}<br>
          <strong>y coordinate:</strong> ${d["y"]}<br>
          <strong>radius:</strong> ${d["r"]}
          `
          )
          .style("opacity", 0.7);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function (event, d) {
        tooltip.style("display", "none");
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .attr("cx", (d) => {
        return xscale(d["x"]);
      })
      .attr("class", "pointCircleInvisible")

      //same must be done for the y scale
      .attr("cy", (d) => yscale(d["y"]))
      .attr("r", (d) => d["r"])
      .attr("fill", (d) => d["color"])
      .attr("transform", `translate(${calculateMarginLeft(margin.left)},${0})`)
      .attr("opacity", "0.5");
  }, [data, dimensions]);

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-lg-1"></div>
      <div className="col-lg-10 chart-div" ref={wrapperRef}>
        <svg ref={mySVGRef}></svg>
        <div ref={myTooltipRef}></div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-lg-1"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BubleChart;
```